# Why do I get the error "Array initializer must be an initializer list" when I'm trying to return this array in a function?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, initialization

I am coming from Java, and I'm very new to Objective C. Anyway, I have this static method which is designed to **make a copy of an array** *(if there's a better way to accomplish this, please let me know, but I'm asking this question more-so to find out why I got this error and how to avoid such an error in the future.)* I ran into some problems with it, but just when I thought I had them all sorted out, I got this error that looked like [image: XCode]

Here is the method in the interface:

```
+ (float[]) copyArray: (float[]) array withLength: (int) length;
```

And here is the method in the implementation:

```
+ (float[]) copyArray: (float[]) array withLength: (int) length
{
    float copiedArray[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        copiedArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return copiedArray;
}
```

Comment: Hello there is a related post on stackoverflow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: @demo.b already looked at it, but that doesn't work for me because I am declaring this array with a variable length. It won't compile if I try any of the approaches in the accepted answer.

Comment: because you try to return a stack value

Comment: and because float[] != float[count]

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks, that's actually very informative because the same problem doesn't appear at all in Java.

Comment: yip java has no stack vs heap... and all arrays are basically pointers (always)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

method/function cannot return C array. you should do this

```
+ (void) copyArrayFrom:(float *)array to:(float *)toArray withLength: (unsigned) length
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        toArray [i] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Now if you don't mind, do you think I should be using C-style arrays and your method, or just stick to NSArrays. My application is really memory-intensive, so if C-style is faster, that would be really important.

Comment: Nonsense. Objective-C methods can return any C type.

Comment: @jlehr What do you mean?

Comment: @doctordoder depends. if these array are used for OpenGL/CoreGraphics/Other C API, use C array. if you are passing them around to other ObjC API, use NSArray

Comment: The answer incorrectly states: "method/function cannot return C array." That's completely false.

Comment: @jlehr it is possible to return C *pointer*, but not C *array*. but return *pointer* will make memory management a mess

Comment: @BryanChen I'm just designing a fairly simple application with XCode on their default OpenGL template, but it's still going to need to be as conservative on memory as possible.

Answer (score 6):

If all you really want is to copy the first *n* elements from one C array into another *already existing* array, probably the best way is to simply use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(targetArray, sourceArray, sizeof(sourceArray[0]) * numElements);
```

The `sizeof(sourceArray[0])` calculates the byte-size of the type in your array (in your case, it's equivalent to `sizeof(float)`.

Answer (score 2):

C arrays are way more tricky than Java arrays. One of the biggest issues is that in a lot of instances, you don't know how large a C array is unless you have saved this information in a different variable, for example. The [C FAQ "Arrays and Pointers"](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) lists a lot of traps and they apply to Objective-C as well. You might want to see question 6.5 in particular.

As @lwxted already suggested, try to avoid C arrays unless you really know what you're doing and you have determined that you need them. C arrays *are* faster than `NSArray` but unless you have determined that your array really is a performance bottleneck by *measuring with a profiler* you will most likely not notice any difference.

And I strongly recommend avoiding a C array of Objective-C objects (`id objects[]`) unless you *really, really* know very well what you are doing (memory management issues).

Comment: Thanks man. I think I'll compromise by using C-style arrays for primitives like floats, and NSArrays for all my instances.

Comment: It's a reasonable approach (I do this as well sometimes). But beware the memory pitfalls :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, unless for particular needs, a better way to handle this usually is to use the `NSArray` as opposed to C arrays.

```
[NSArray arrayWithArray: array];
```

will copy an `array`.

Besides, in this case, if you insist on using C arrays, the use of implicitly typed length `float[]` is advised against. A better way is to use pointers to manipulate arrays.

Also, the stack-allocated array would be invalid after leaving the function, since it's local only in the scope of the `copyArray` function. You should dynamically allocate memory, if you wish the array to be valid outside the scope.

Comment: +1, I was also going to suggest avoiding C arrays unless there is a very good reason to go for a C array. But all you need then is `[myArray copy]`, not a dedicated method.

Comment: Why would you ever write a method that does nothing but return the value returned by `[NSArray arrayWithArray:]`?

Comment: Yeah... Just trying to make the point that `NSArray` should be used. Fixed.

Comment: @jlehr because I want to deal with the float[]-style array because my application deals a lot with OpenGL. Coming from Java, that was the way to do it, but if NSArray works just as well as the regular float[]-style array, then this method would be totally pointless, yes.

Comment: `[array copy]` is easier than `[NSArray arrayWithArray: array]`

Comment: Ok, like I  predicted in my question, there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, at least for an NSArray, but is this possible with just a float[]-style, or other primitive[]-style array?

Comment: I believe you can use a C array; you should dynamically allocate the memory in the function though. Using pointer is also more recommended than using `float[]`.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with all the points @DarkDust makes, if you're working with a C API such as OpenGL, there may be situations where using `NSArray` and `NSNumber` vs. C arrays of type `float` will have performance impacts. As always, try to use the simpler approach first, and carefully measure performance before deciding to optimize.

In any case, to answer the original question, here's how to correctly return a copy of a C array:

```
+ (float *)copyOfCArray:(float *)array withLength:(int)length
{
    float *copyOfArray = malloc(length * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        copyOfArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    return copyOfArray;
}
```

Also, there's arguably no need to make the above a method at all. Instead, consider writing it as a C function:

```
float *CopyArray(float *array, int length)
{
    // Implementation would be the same...
}
```

Comment: don't do this. it will leak memory. because someone will forget to call `free` on returned value. BTW `sizeof(array)/sizeof(float)` does not make sense (it will be 1 in most of the cases)

Comment: @BryanChen Heh, you're right, the sizeof stuff I grabbed from a slightly different context. Updating now.

Comment: @jlehr Wow, those look like the fastest and most concise approaches, but before I really move forward with this, when you say "the simplest approach," I agree, but do you mean that using an NSArray is the simplest approach?

Comment: @BryanChen Function naming conventions convey the same kinds of things about memory management semantics as method names, so a method or function that begins with `copy` or `create` implies ownership.

Comment: @doctordoder Heh, that depends to some degree on the developer. The answer might be different for an ace C programmer with little experience in Objective-C. But yes, `NSArray` and other Foundation classes are extremely powerful wrappers around low-level C code that can be very tricky to write and maintain correctly.

Comment: still, this does add one more way to leak memory. and you stop the possibility to allocate memory on stack (when size is small).

Comment: @BryanChen And that's the nature of optimizations -- they generally add some complexity and risk in order to achieve better performance. Note, I didn't recommend starting with this approach, but it does directly answer the OP's original question, (though @DarkDust's suggestion to use `memcpy` is even better).

Comment: I think I'll move forward with the NSArrays then, and once my application is fully-functional, I'll start profiling and optimizing